# Is it possible to write auto-cast operator outside a struct?

Tags: c++, casting, operator-keyword

The exact situation is next:
I have defined in system API structs `CGPoint` and `CGSize`, and I want to be able to write `my_point = my_size`.
I can't modify `CGPoint` struct, only can write external operator. I can write binary operators (`+`, `-`, ...) but `operator=` must by declared inside struct. So is there any other solution?

Comment: What is the connection between a point and a size? How can the size be a point? Sounds like different dimensions.

Comment: @BoPersson I fail to see the relevance of your question. How does their relationship change the syntax by which one writes such an operator?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To make the expression `a = b;` compile you need to either have an `operator=` in the type of `a` that takes an element of the type of `b`, or a type implicitly convertible from `b`.

The first case is ruled out, since `operator=` must be a member of the class, and since you cannot modify `GLPoint` then you cannot add `GLPoint& GLPoint::operator=( GLSize )`.

The second case suffers the same type of problems. An implicit conversion from `GLSize` to `GLPoint` can be implemented as an implicit constructor in `GLPoint` (ruled out), or as a member `operator GLPoint()` in `GLSize`, which requires modification of `GLSize`. Conversions cannot be added as free functions either.

The alternatives are using non-operator syntax, as adding a free function `assign` (or `copy`): `GLPoint& assign( GLPoint&, GLSize const & )`.

The next question is why would you want to do so. If the designers of `GLPoint` and `GLSize` did not consider that a size should be assignable to a point, then why do you feel that they should be assignable? In general it is a good idea to keep types separate, as that will enable the compiler to detect mistakes you might make in your code.

If you allow implicit conversions from `GLSize` to `GLPoint`, you might by mistake type something like: `distance( point1, size2 )` where you meant `distance( point1, point2 )`, and because there is a conversion, the compiler will gladly convert and apply. Then you will see strange results, and you will spend quite a few *nice* debugging hours trying to determine where the logic is wrong.

Unless the domain has a very clear definition of what each operator means in that context, I would avoid operator overloading at all costs. Will *everyone* reading your code immediately understand what `GLPoint(1,2) + GLSize(5)` represents without any doubt or ambiguity? If that is not the case, if people will be surprised or even doubt, then avoid operator overloading and use named functions: `move_up( GLPoint&, GLSize )` (or whatever point+size means to you)

Comment: +1, excellent commentary on the pitfalls of conversion operators

Comment: Excellent commentary in general, with the analysis of the underlying semantics.  (Obviously based on the names, but if his assumptions are wrong, the names are very poorly chosen.)

Comment: I understand the concept mistakes :) But following them brings some discomfort (large code: I must write CGPoint (my_size.width, my_size.height) each time). I have solved the problem partly by template function that casts any type to CGPoint. Yes, I understand the concept mistakes :)

Comment: @brigadir: or just add a function: `inline GLPoint pointFromSize( GLSize const & );` and use it: `point = pointFromSize( size1 );` which is very easy to parse for a human. The point is that operator overloading reduces typing, but it makes code more obscure, to interpret a line `a+b` you have to read back to the definitions. Also, what is the result of `point+size`, is it a `point`, a `size`, depends on the order of the arguments?

Comment: In my situation I must use CGSize when dealing with system API, but in my code I try to convert all to CGPoint (such as it represents any 2D entity). The sense of CGPoint variable is defined by it's name and context.

Comment: `Why would you want to do so. If the designers of GLPoint and GLSize did not consider that a size should be assignable to a point, then why do you feel that they should be assignable?`   Here’s an example of why one would want to do this: `LARGE_INTEGER` is a struct which cannot be implicitly converted to/from `LONGLONG` even though it contains one in the `QuadPart` member. One (I) would want to write a conversion operator to make it easier to use the `PLI` type in functions and assignments instead of having to use a extra, separate line such as when calling `SetFilePointerEx`.

Comment: This is the only answer that addresses the question at all.

Comment: Is there any documentation regarding the `assign` syntax, or is this just normal function? I need to make type conversion between two different variant types.

Answer (score 4):

If you can derive from or wrap CGPoint and use the new class instead throughout your code, then you can provide whatever operators you like.  The new class can have a conversion operator to `CGPoint` facilitating interaction with existing functions.

Comment: This is prone to be more problematic than helpful. Inheritance is the second most coupling relationship and should be avoided unless it does make sense, and in this case I don't think it does. Consider that existing code will still return the non-derived type, and then you will be mixing points that can be assigned with points that cannot. Worse than that, the current system might expect containers of `GLPoint`, if it is by-value, then it won't accept the new type, if it is by pointer, and it tries to `delete` internally, then you are in Undefined Behavior land...

Comment: @David: they're certainly considerations that should guide the choice of derivation versus wrapping/composition, and could make the techniques I've listed inappropriate for a particular problem.  The balance depends on how many points of interaction there are with functions that would need "real" GLPoints, versus the amount of code internal to the app that might benefit from the convenience of this assignment notation.  Up to the OP to assess their case.

Answer (score 3):

When you assign a `CGSize` to a `CGPoint` - what happens? Distil that into some operator and there you have it - for example

```
CGPoint& operator|=(CGPoint& cPoint, CGSize const& cSize)
{
  // now set attributes of cPoint that you can extract from cSize

  return cPoint;
}
```

What's so difficult about this? Here is an example: http://www.ideone.com/FZN20

Comment: It's good solution for simple case, I want to operate with CGSize in expressions...

Comment: `I want to [use it] in expressions`     Exactly. For example in my case, I want to do something like `LONGLONG size=blah(); SetFilePointerEx(fh, size, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);` instead of having to do `LONGLONG size=blah(); LARGE_INTEGER tli={0}; tli.QuadPart=size; SetFilePointerEx(fh, tli, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);` If I can write something like `LARGE_INTEGER operator=(LONGLONG ll) {LARGE_INTEGER li={0}; li.QuadPart=ll; return li;}` (or a conversion operator), then it would create cleaner code that is easier to use and understand.

Comment: I prefer `operator<<`

Answer (score 2):

Other answers seams to miss the obvious solution : add a function to convert CGPoint into CGSize. Off course, that is not exactly what you want (`size = point`), but since you can not modify either of two classes, this is the only way :

```
CGSize ToSize( const CGPoint &pt )
{
  CGSize res = ...
  // do the conversion
  return res;
}
```

Comment: It’s not as ideal as actually using operators, but it should work most of the time. (Actually, it makes it even more confusing that operators cannot be made to do it since a regular function-call can.)

Comment: @Synetech My experience is that conversion operators can introduce confusions, and are better to avoid

Comment: In many case sure, but if the original dev who made the class did not design it well enough, then using a conversion operator could (have) made it easier to use, like with LARGE_INTEGERs.