# Type conversion in free functions

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

Using libraries like `jsoncpp` to serialize my C++ objects and data (e.g. to plot them in Python), I really get tired of all the loops in my code to convert `std::vector< double >`s into `Json::Value`s. I end up re-typing the same lines again and again. Therefore I'd like to make this a little easier.

I have two use cases: Convert `STL` types (at least `std::vector`, `std::map`) from and to `Json::Value`, and do this with my own data types as well.

Solution for own data types:

- define constructor expecting `const Json::Value&`, the constructor then tries to fill the object with data or throws exceptions if the passed value does not meet specific requirements
- define `operator Json::Value()` as a member function of my class.

This way, I should be able to write stuff like that:

```
MyObj o;
Json::Value root;
root["foo"] = o;
MyObj reconstructed(root["foo"]);
```

But how should I do this with `STL` types? Write explicit functions, maybe templates, or should I do the same like for my own data types, except that I use free functions instead of member functions? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a single function to do that, using [for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/).

If you want to support nested containers (vector in vector etc), then you need wrapper functions and call the function recursively, until the input type allows straight conversion to a Json::Value.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited my question: It makes me tired to repeat the same piece of code again and again, so it's desireable to have implicit conversion for me. I know how to convert a vector into a Json::Value in little code, but don't know *where* to put the appropriate code.

Comment: Eh... Just put it in a function and put it in utility file that includes Jsoncpp. If I have such utility files that depend on a library, I usually call the file pair: nameofthelib_util .h/cpp or NameofthelibUtil.h/cpp.

Comment: My question is: Are the functions explicit, like "vec_to_json" or are they implicit, like my `operator` example above ... more a "best practice" than a "I don't know how this works at all".

Comment: You cannot add an explicit conversion operator to Json::Value, unless you want to change the class yourself. That is covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120841/is-it-possible-to-write-auto-cast-operator-outside-a-struct). In your case, you can just add a new function that returns a Json::Value object.

Comment: Thank you, the SO post was exactly my missing link.